# Two reservation at the same time create duplicate ID in custom format

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a reservation system in PHP & MySQL with custom running numbers.

The format is like this: XXX01, XXX02, XXX03 etc'

Every day the format reset to zero and the XXX is also change.
For this reason I can't use auto increment to create the format.

The problem begins that sometimes reservation are created at exactly same second, becuse of that there is a duplication in the reservation number (Like two reservation with the ID XXX03).
Does anyone have any idea how to solve this?
Thanks.

Edit - This is the PHP code that create the ID (codeignitor 3):

```
$this->CI->db->select('reservation_inside_id');
$this->CI->db->where('DATE(reservation_insert_time)',date("Y-m-d"));
$this->CI->db->from($this->table);
$this->CI->db->order_by('reservation_inside_id DESC');
$this->CI->db->limit(1);
       
$query = $this->CI->db->get();
$row = $query->result();
if (isset($row[0]->reservation_inside_id)) {
    $some_string = THE_FORMAT; //irrelevant
    $inside_id = $some_string.$row[0]->reservation_inside_id;
    $inside_id++;
    return $inside_id;
} else {
    return NEW_ID //here is OK
}
```

Comment: If we could see the code that is doing this we may be able to help

Comment: set index for that column as `UNIQUE`. So if at same time 2 records are inserted, it will give insert error for 2nd insert. in code, if you get this error then run your insert query again

Comment: Are you searching for a PHP solution, or a MySQL solution? If you don't even use auto increments, why did you tag your question with it?

Comment: Without the code this is hard to answer. My guess is, that you are adressing your backend  from multiple clients without even checking for parallel actions. When you have multiple clients, you should implement some kind of Broker-Service that is working through your requests in a sequential order. Very basic way to do this: insert every request into a temporary SQL-table. Your reservation service is working through this table from top to bottom. This way, there can be no duplicates.

Comment: Maybe it could help to insert the row without any reservation number, and assign it through a central job (cronjob or messaging queue) in a second step?

Comment: Fix your design; you're storing denormalised data.

Comment: You all guys are right. i update and add the PHP code.
I also deleted the wrong tagging.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is a big part of the reason why sequence generators [eg: `AUTO_INCREMENT`] exist, and that is "concurrent access". Unfortunately mysql does not have any way to easily define a custom sequence generator, so we'll need to bodge one together.

First we need a table that will hold the sequence state:

```sql
CREATE TABLE sequence_meta (
  id       INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  prefix   VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  counter  INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO sequence_meta (prefix, counter)
  VALUES ('PRE', 1);
```

And an example table to apply the sequence to:

```sql
CREATE TABLE example (
  id        VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  something VARCHAR(255)
);
```

Now to make sure that we don't have more than one query contending over the sequence's state we need to wrap all modifications to the table in a transaction like so:

```sql
START TRANSACTION;

SELECT prefix, counter
FROM sequence_meta
WHERE id = 1
FOR UPDATE; -- this locks the row

-- PHP code happens here, eg:
--   $row_id = $row['prefix'] . str_pad($row['counter'], 4, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);

INSERT INTO example (id, something)
  VALUES ( $row_id, 'hello' );

-- but that was a prepared statement, right? right.

-- now we can update the sequence metadata

UPDATE sequence_meta SET counter = counter + 1 WHERE id = 1;

COMMIT; -- this makes all changes effective, and releases the lock
```

We can also wrap this up in a more compact `INSERT SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` query:

```sql
START TRANSACTION;

INSERT INTO example ( id, something )
  SELECT
    CONCAT(prefix, LPAD(counter, 4, 0)) AS 'id',
    'world' as `something`
  FROM sequence_meta
  FOR UPDATE
;

UPDATE sequence_meta SET counter = counter + 1 WHERE id = 1;

COMMIT;
```

After which we might ahve something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM sequence_meta;
```

| id | prefix | counter |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | PRE | 3 |

```
SELECT *
FROM example;
```

| id | something |
| --- | --- |
| PRE0001 | hello |
| PRE0002 | world |

and then you can have a cron that runs once per day at midnight to:

```sql
UPDATE sequence_meta
SET
  prefix = 'FOO',
  counter = 1
WHERE id = 1;
```

Which doesn't necessarily need to be wrapped in an explicit transaction since it is a single atomic statement that inherently locks the row. Just make sure that your cron task *never* re-uses a prefix, or you're going to have a real bad time.

You should extend this further and turn it into a stored procedure, an example of which is in the second edit below.

*All that being said*, this is a whole lot of trouble for dubious benefit. I would just use an `AUTO_INCREMENT` ID column, plus creation date/time, and use those to *compute* a "friendly" ID if necessary. Making a custom sequence generator is a lot of legwork, not to mention has a lot of surface area for things to go wrong. Eg:

- Ensuring that all sequence table accesses are wrapped in a locking transaction.
- Making sure that the cron that updates the sequence table *never* fails or skips for any reason.
- Writing your prefix generator to *never* produce a duplicate value.

Etc, etc. YMMV

**Edit:**

It should be noted that even in the above code there was at least one consequential design choice made, and that is that the lock on the sequence table is open for the entire transaction, which may be a fair performance hit. The way that Mysql addresses this is that any time an ID *might* be needed, one is issued. This ensures that the sequence is locked for the minimum amount of time, at the expense of the potential for 'holes' in the sequence.

Also, *never* backfill holes in generated sequences. Here be dragons.

**Edit2:**

Ok, I nerd-sniped myself and finally read up on procedures/functions. Since this contains a transaction it *must* be a procedure, so it's still a little clunky, but still better than implementing a lot of boilerplate query code.

```sql
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE get_seq (
  IN  seq_id INTEGER UNSIGNED,
  OUT seq    VARCHAR(255)
)
BEGIN
  START TRANSACTION;
  
  SELECT
    concat(prefix, LPAD(counter, 4, '0'))
  INTO seq
  FROM sequence_meta
  WHERE id = seq_id
  FOR UPDATE;
  
  UPDATE sequence_meta SET counter = counter + 1 WHERE id = seq_id;
  
  COMMIT;
END//
  
DELIMITER ;
```

Example use:

```sql
CALL get_seq(1, @new_id);

INSERT INTO example ( id, something )
  VALUES( @new_id, 'hello world!');
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try calling the `getLastInsertReservation()` method before saving to the database. This method would ask MySQL for the last inserted row and only on this basis you could make it for yourself.

In addition, if you want to avoid repetition, you can make a key consisting of several indexes. In this case Set date and key as primary key. There is no option for the same key to occur several times on a given date.

In short, you can set the index not by id but by columns that together are to be unique

Comment: `$id = get_last_row_id() + 1;` is prone to failure in the case that there was previously a row at that ID which was deleted. Re-using a deleted ID is dangerous in that there is the possibility of data that was associated with the previous record, but not cleaned up, being incorrectly associated with the new. Or something like an invoice issued against the previous owner of the ID being enforced against the new owner.

Answer (score -1):

Create a table with an `AUTO_INCREMENT` id and use that id to generate your reservation code.

```sql
CREATE TABLE `reservation` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    `code` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `customer_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL
);

#Insert data and get id
$data = [
    'code' => '',
    'customer_name' => 'XYZ ABC',
];
$this->db->insert('reservation', $data);
$last_insert_id = $this->db->insert_id();

#Use $last_insert_id to update reservation code.

$this->db->where('id',$last_insert_id);
$this->db->set('code', 'CONCAT("XXX", LPAD(id, 2, 0))', FALSE);
$this->db->update('reservation');
```

This line `CONCAT('XXX', LPAD(id, 2, 0))` will generate format like XXX01, XXX02, XXX03 etc.
Reservation code is generated with `AUTO_INCREMENT` id to prevent duplication.

Above code will generate data like this in reservation table:

| id | code | customer_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | XXX01 | XYZ ABC |
| 2 | XXX02 | XYZ ABC |

Comment: Please never recommend the usage of insecure database queries

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).